# Set anchor as active with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

i have short question.. i got 3 content boxes and all have a menu with anchor-links to the 
content-boxes below!
when i visit the site the first anchor is set ti active..
when i click now on no.2 in headline 1 it jumps to the 2nd anchor.. but the problem is i have to scroll a little bit above with the mousewheel to set the 2nd anchor as active.

and backwards too.
when i click on box3 at anchor1..

any ideas to solve the problem?

**WHEN SCROLLING UP AND DOWN IT WORKS PERFECT! JUST THE JUMP OVER THE ANCHOR MADE PROBLEMS**

**here is the demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/wv9EQ/

here is the javascript code:

```
$(function(){
    var sections = {},
        _height  = $(window).height(),
        i        = 0;

    //// Grab positions of our sections
    $('.section').each(function(){
        sections[this.name] = $(this).offset().top;
    });

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            pos   = $this.scrollTop();

        for(i in sections){
            if(sections[i] > pos && sections[i] < pos + _height){
                $('a').removeClass('active');
                $('.nav_' + i).addClass('active');
            }  
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT: i can't add active to all links! i include this small navi as php and its dynamic for all boxes! 
when i set all to active than are all anchors active :D**

Comment: Why do you need that for (i in sections). Isn't this the result you want http://jsfiddle.net/wv9EQ/6/ ?

Comment: I only added the "active" css class to the corresponding <a/> tags in each section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same sort of thing when a link is clicked:

```
$('.head-nav-button').click(function()
{
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav_' + $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')).addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wv9EQ/7/

Answer (score 1):

for your code use the simple way

http://jsfiddle.net/wv9EQ/4/

```
  <li><a href="#2-SP" class="head-nav-button nav_2-SP active">2. SP.</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
for(i in sections){
        if(sections[i] > pos && sections[i] < pos + _height){
            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $('.nav_' + i).addClass('active');
        }  
    }
```

And just add the "active" class where you need it like here http://jsfiddle.net/wv9EQ/6/

Comment: Run the same code when clicking the <a/> tag as you do when scrolling