# find anchor and set active with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

i have 3 content boxes and all have a menu with anchor-links to the content-boxes below!
(the links are included and dynamic)

yesterday i [received help with the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306545/set-anchor-as-active-with-jquery).. and its working very good when i have a large content-box.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9EQ/7/

now i got an problem when i have an small content-box

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9EQ/8/

when i am for example between box 2 and 3 both anchors getting active.
any ideas to fix that? i just want an active anchor only for the box i am currently inside

i use this script:

```
$(function(){
    var sections = {},
        _height  = $(window).height(),
        i        = 0;

    //// Grab positions of our sections
    $('.section').each(function(){
        sections[this.name] = $(this).offset().top;
    });

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            pos   = $this.scrollTop();

        for(i in sections){
            if(sections[i] > pos && sections[i] < pos + _height){
                $('a').removeClass('active');
                $('.nav_' + i).addClass('active');
            }  
        }
    });

    $('.head-nav-button').click(function()
    {
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav_' + $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the function after setting a section to active: http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/nCasy/

Comment: hi Dr.Molle.. have the same problem when im between headline2 and 3 both 2-SP anchors are active.. and a problem with your scrript.. when i am for example on head3 and press 1-SP it jumps to the top  but set 2-SP active

Comment: set this condition: `sections[i] >pos` to: `sections[i] >=pos` , because the related .section is equal to pos when you use the links : http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/nCasy/9/

Comment: you fixed the bug!! cool.. but i there is an other problem.. i try to explain: when 1 visit the site first anchor is set because the site loads ontop (everthing is fine) when i start scrolling or press anchor 3 for example all 3 boxes are active on anchor 3. i just want the anchor in the active box (and not all 3) when scrolling or clicking.. sorry for the misstake

Comment: maybe its easier to set permantly box 1 anchor 1 as active, in box2 anchor 2 and so on.. ?

Comment: It's not difficult, simply set the context of the element you like to mark as active to the related box: `$('.section[name="'+i+'"]').parent()` . Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/4uqKg/

Comment: maybe you can visit the chat? i have a small question :D

Comment: ok no problem.. nevertheless thanks for your help :D and greetings from GER :D

Answer (score 1):

Using a offset and `break` after the first activated menu seems to work:

**Trivial parts:**

```
offset   = 50; // Should be at least the height of your nav bar

if(sections[i] - pos + offset > 0){
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav_' + i).addClass('active');
    break;            
}
```

Full code in fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wv9EQ/10/